# Show specific path's files recursively with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, treeview, create-react-app

I'm beginner of React,

and I create my react app by `create-react-app`

As I known, I need to put the files under `public` folder as below.

```
my-app
│  .gitignore
│  package-lock.json
│  package.json
│  README.md
│         
├─public
│      a.stl
│      b.stl
│      c.stl
│      cat.jpg
│      dog.jpg
│      exported.stl
│      favicon.ico
│      index.html
│      logo192.png
│      logo512.png
│      manifest.json
│      robots.txt
└─src
        App.css
        App.js
        App.test.js
        index.css
        index.js
        logo.svg
        reportWebVitals.js
        setupTests.js
        Viewer.js
```

So that I can use the file as

```js
<img src"dog.jpg" />
```

Why the root folder is `public`? Can I change it?

I want to show files recursivly as tree view by given specific path

Such as show `public`'s files on the webpage by React.

```js
// App.js

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            **<TreeView src="public" />**
            **<TreeView src="specific/path/of/react/server" />**
        );
    }
};
export default App;
```

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks